# can i put multiple value in .val

Tags: jquery, google-api

Can i put multiple value in `$(this).val();` from

```
function showRoom1(room){
    var valx = $(this).val();
    for( var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++ ) {
        var xa = '[' + gmarkers[i].rmcat + ']';
        if(arrayBox(xa,valx) == true) { 
            gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);}
        }
   }
```

from this input

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="showRoom1(this)" name="room_5" value="5" checked="checked" />
<input type="hidden" onclick="showRoom1(this)" name="room_6" value="6" checked="checked" />
<input type="hidden" onclick="showRoom1(this)" name="room_7" value="7" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: A bit more code/explanation would be good. Not very clear currently

Comment: edited already, sorry i don't know how to explain more than this.

Comment: @user3124541 Sorry, I still don't understand your question

Comment: You could explain what you're trying to achieve fully, how you want to handle the data afterwards etc. Either way you will probably need to look into arrays or something